# mysql триггер, где ошибка?

Tags: mysql, триггер

Подскажите где тут ошибка?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `updateBonusTable` AFTER UPDATE ON `character_subclasses` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF(NEW.level = 85) AND (OLD.level != 85) THEN
        SET @charName = (select `char_name` from `characters` WHERE `obj_Id` = NEW.char_obj_id LIMIT 1);
      INSERT into ttgBonus.bonus_85_lvl (`charName`) VALUES(@charName);
END IF;
END;
```

Пишет ошибку Ошибка SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: Скорее всего вы не переопределили признак конца запроса ;, например в консольном клиенте mysql это делается при помощи команды DELIMITER. Например DELIMITER //, тогда после END следует указывать не точку с запятой, а //, внутренние же точки с запятыми не будут конфликтовать с признаком конца запроса.

Comment: @cheops спасибо, ответьте на вопрос я признаю его верным

Comment: Странный текст триггера. Требует допущения, что подзапрос и так вернёт 1 запись, либо что во всех записях `char_name` один и тот же. И в принципе всё легко сворачивается в один запрос, так что DELIMITER переопределять и не придётся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно такая ошибка возникает в том случае, если не переопределяется признак конца запроса - точка с запятой. В этом случае она конфликтует с точками запятыми в теле триггера.

Если запрос выполняется в консольной утилите mysql, лучше всего переопределить признак конца запроса при помощи команды `DELIMITER` (графические клиенты, как правило, так же предоставляют такую возможность). Это позволяет обойти конфликт.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `updateBonusTable` AFTER UPDATE ON `character_subclasses` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF(NEW.level = 85) AND (OLD.level != 85) THEN
        SET @charName = (select `char_name` from `characters` WHERE `obj_Id` = NEW.char_obj_id LIMIT 1);
      INSERT into ttgBonus.bonus_85_lvl (`charName`) VALUES(@charName);
END IF;
END//
```

После создания триггера, можно восстановить старый признак конца запроса при помощи команды

```
DELIMITER ;
```